# Core Data Group by attribute from another Entity

Tags: xcode, swift, core-data

I have two entities with one-to-many relationship between them, and I would like to group by attribute from another Entity.

```
  let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Entity1", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)

  fetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = ["Entity2.attributeFromEntity2"]
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is discussed in various blog posts.

Here's one: [CORE DATA AND AGGREGATE FETCHES IN SWIFT by Matt Long](http://www.cimgf.com/2015/06/25/core-data-and-aggregate-fetches-in-swift/)

Comment: Thanks. But isn't that example made using 1 entity?

Comment: Extending it to your application is probably quite straight forward. If not, could you describe how?